# What workflow can mitigate git merge conflicts when a file is renamed and a new file is created with the old name?

Tags: git, merge, rename, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

**Problem**

1. I have root branch `master` and `feature` branched from master.
2. `master` has file `A`
3. `feature` has moved file `A` to `B` and created a new file `A`
4. Work in `master` against file `A` needs to be merged into `feature` branch file `B`
5. Merging `master` into `feature` results in a merge conflict. `master` file `A` tries to be merged into `feature` file `A` even though `master` `A` and `feature` `A` are no longer related.
   How do I tell git to instead merge `master` `A` into `feature` `B`?

**Steps Reproduce**

In a console:

```
mkdir git_rename_demo
cd git_rename_demo

git init

echo "LineB1\nLineB2\nLineB3\nLineB4" > A.txt
git add A.txt
git commit -m "Add A"

git checkout -b rename_A_to_B
git mv A.txt B.txt
echo "LineA1\nLineA2\nLineA3" > A.txt
git add A.txt
git commit -m "Moved Old A to B and Added New A"

git checkout master
echo "LineB5\nLineB5" >> A.txt
git add A.txt
git commit -m "Added More LineBs to A"

git checkout rename_A_to_B
git merge master
```

**Scenario**

I have a `master` branch and a `feature` branch. A file, `A` on the `master` containing code that does "A" related logic.

On the `feature` branch, it was discovered that file `A` didn't make sense as a file name because the code is more related to "B" logic. Simultaneously, new code was written that does relate to "A" logic in `feature` branch. To fix this, file `A` was renamed to file `B`, effectively meaning all original "B" related logic in file `A` has been moved to new file `B`. All new "A" related logic was added to a new file called `A`, effectively replacing the old `A` file.

Work has continued on `master` branch, adding more "B" logic to the `A` file that still exist there. This is the file, that on the `feature` branch has been renamed to `B`.

The time comes where work from `master` needs to be merged into `feature`, as feature will continue to be developed separately from `master` until a later date. The merge of `master` into `feature` results in the conflict outlined above.  We need to continue to allow developers working on `master` to do "B" related work against `A` and be able to merge that `A` file work into `feature` branch `B` file without having to manually resolve the conflict each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There is no really good way to handle this, but you can do it somewhat manually.  See below.

#### Long

Don't worry too much about *branch names*.  Do worry about *commits*; merge is based on commits, not branch names.  Branch names just help you, and Git, *find* particular commits.  A branch name always contains the raw commit hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch, by definition.  Adding a new commit consists of:

1. Check out the branch by name, so that Git knows which branch name to update in step 3.  This makes the tip commit of the branch be the *current* commit.  The special name `HEAD` is now attached to the branch name, and therefore, `HEAD` selects the *current* commit, which is the last (or *tip*) commit in the branch.
2. Make a new commit, in the usual way.  Git will create the commit, setting its parent to the current commit.  This new commit will get its own unique hash ID, different from that of every prior commit, and different from every future commit too.
3. At this point, having made the new commit, Git writes the *new* commit's hash ID into a branch name: the one to which `HEAD` is attached.  So now the branch name points to the *last* (tip) commit in the branch.  That new commit points back to what used to be the tip; the branch is now one commit longer.

Whenever you do a real merge (there are some fake kinds of merges), there are three commits involved:

- the *merge base*, which is the best common ancestor to the other two commits;
- your *current commit* (or `HEAD`), usually the tip of a branch;<sup>1</sup> and
- the commit you select in your command line: often, the tip of another branch.

Git finds the merge base commit on its own.  You just name the other commit.  If you want to see, in advance, which commit is the merge base, you can run:

```
git merge-base --all other
```

where `other` is whatever you plan to supply to the `git merge` command, from which Git picks the third commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other option is that you may be in *detached HEAD* state, in which the special name `HEAD` just contains the raw hash ID of the commit itself.  Either way, `HEAD` names the *current commit*.  It just does so *using a branch name* when you're on a branch.  But normally you're on a branch when you run merge.

---

#### How merge works in a nutshell, which is also where your problem comes from

Imagine a simplified commit timeline, with later commits towards the right, in which we replace the commit hashes with single uppercase letters to make it easier to talk about them.  We might have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here the name `branch1` finds, or *points to*, our current commit, whose hash ID is `J`.  The name `branch2` points to commit `L`.  We'd like to merge branch `branch2` into `branch1`, which really means merge commit `L` into commit `J` to produce new merge commit `M`.  Git *automatically* finds the best *shared* commit, which is commit `H`: the last commit that's on *both* branches.

In order to merge our changes with their changes, Git has to figure out what we changed, and what they changed.  Since each commit holds a full snapshot of all files, that's relatively easy: Git will diff the snapshot in commit `H` against the snapshot in our `HEAD` commit `J`, to see what *we* changed.  And, Git will also diff the snapshot in `H` vs that in `L`, to see what *they* changed.

You can run these two `git diff` commands on your own:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

**This is where your issue comes in:** `--find-renames` in the first `git diff` *would* find that file `A` in the merge base, which presumably is also called `A` in their commit, is now called `B` in your HEAD commit.  So the diff would pair up "A in base, B in ours" and compare the contents.  That's what *we* changed: the contents changed, and the file's *name* changed.

The second `git diff` would pair up "A in base, A in theirs" to see what they changed.  When merge goes to *combine* the changes, that would all work.  The combined changes would be:

- whatever we changed, if anything, plus renaming the file;
- whatever they changed, if anything.

Git would apply these combined changes to the snapshot in commit `H`, which would rename the file.

But for Git to *find* the rename in the first place, Git *must not* pair up file `A` in commit `H` with a file named `A` in commit the `--ours` commit (`J`).  If a file named `A` exists, Git *automatically assumes* that it's "the same" file.

When you run `git diff` manually like this, you can add an extra option to tell Git *not* to assume that.  When `git merge` runs `git diff` on its own, it never provides this option.

Note that for all other files, everything works OK.  Suppose that in file *F1*, which has the same name in all three commits, you changed some early lines, and they changed some later lines.  Git applies *both* changes to the copy of *F1* from `H`, and moves on to the next file.

At some point, though, Git might hit some file—maybe *F2*—where you and they changed *the same* lines.  Git will now stop and make you clean up the mess.

Git leaves you *four* files, not just one, with the mess in them:

- There's a copy of file *F2* from the merge base in Git's *index*.
- There's a copy of file *F2* from your commit in Git's index.
- There's a copy of file *F2* from their commit in Git's index.
- Last, there's Git's best effort at *combining* these changed files, in the work-tree.

The work-tree files are the ones you are used to using.  They are right there, to be seen and edited and compiled or whatever it is you do with files.

The copies that are in Git's index are hard even to see, but you can get all three of them out with `git show` or with `git checkout`.  The `git mergetool` command does this, extracting a file named F to F.BASE, F.LOCAL, and F.REMOTE ... and then trying to run a merge tool on these three files to produce the merged file F, and then removing these three files.  So mergetool is almost OK, but it does too much.

You can fall back on the `git show` method:

```
git show :1:F > F.LOCAL    # :1: means the merge base version
git show :2:F > F.OURS     # :2: means our version, like `git checkout --ours`
git show :3:F > F.THEIRS   # :3: means their version, like `git checkout --theirs`
```

But in this case, Git is merging the *wrong files*, so this doesn't help directly.  Still, it's important to know.

#### The above is about what goes wrong.  Here is what you *can* do

You ran:

```
git merge other
```

Git found the three commits: base, `HEAD`, and other.  It ran two `git diff`s, from base to `HEAD` to see what you did, and base to other to see what they did.

One of these two diffs should have found a rename, but did not.  It then tried to merge A from the base with A from the local/`--ours` commit and A from the other/`--theirs`/remote commit.

You could extract the three versions of A and then merge them "by hand", kind of like `git mergetool` does.  But the real trick here is that *don't* want A.LOCAL at all, you want B.LOCAL or B.OURS depending on what you like to call it.

You *have* B.LOCAL already.  It's just called `B`.  So what you want is to:

- extract the merge-base version of file `A`: use `git show :1:A > A.base`
- extract their version of file `A`: use `git show :3:A > A.other`
- merge these three files, writing the merge result to file `B`.

OK, the first two bullet points are straightforward.  But now we still have to merge three files.  Well, if you have a merge tool you like, you can use that directly!  If not, we can have Git do it, the same way Git does it automatically, but we control the input files.  We just use the command:

```
git merge-file B A.base A.other
```

which merges our existing `B` with their `A` and `A.other`.  There may be merge conflicts, as usual; they are to be fixed in the usual way now.

Of course Git made a mess of our file `A`, but we can fix that too:

```
git checkout --ours A
```

which extracts `:2:A` from the index into the work-tree, followed by:

```
git add A
```

which removes the three `:1:`, `:2:`, and `:3:` slot entries and puts the checked-out index-version-2 of `A` in as the to-be-committed file `A`.

If you have to do this often, you can script part of it (all except for resolving any actual conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can find an automated solution for this.
But you can create patch from git diff and manually update git apply in the feature branch.